# .net core web app - use custom log category in appsetting.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was wondering about using a minimal .net core web app and setting a logging level for a custom logger name.  Any attempts to edit the appSettings.json don't seem to produce a difference for me.

1. Create a new "ASP.NET Core Web API" project.
2. Uncheck "Use controllers (uncheck to use minimal APIs)
3. Change Program.cs to be:

```cs
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.AddConsole();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddConsole();
    }).CreateLogger("MyCategoryName");
    
    foreach (LogLevel level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(LogLevel)).OfType<LogLevel>())
    {
        bool enabled = logger.IsEnabled(level);
        string enabledString = enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled";
        logger.LogCritical($"Log level {level} is {enabledString}.");
        logger.Log(level, $"Successfully logged to console at level: {level}");
    }
    
    app.Run();
```

5. Change appSettings.development.json to be:

```json
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
          "MyCategoryName": "Error"
        }
      }
    }
```

6. Run the program and just look at the console output ( I cleaned it up a little bit ):

```
Log level Trace is disabled.
Log level Debug is disabled.
Log level Information is enabled.
Successfully logged to console at level: Information
Log level Warning is enabled.
Successfully logged to console at level: Warning
Log level Error is enabled.
Successfully logged to console at level: Error
Log level Critical is enabled.
Successfully logged to console at level: Critical
Log level None is disabled.
```

It looks like Information and above are enabled and logging when I'd only expect error and above.

Attempt #2 - Trying with a controller

1. Create a new "ASP.NET Core Web API" project.
2. Leave this checked - "Use controllers (uncheck to use minimal APIs)
3. Edit the folowing method in WeatherForecastContoller.cs

```cs
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            foreach (LogLevel level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(LogLevel)).OfType<LogLevel>())
            {
                bool enabled = _logger.IsEnabled(level);
                string enabledString = enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled";
                _logger.LogCritical($"Log level {level} is {enabledString}.");
                _logger.Log(level, $"Successfully logged to console at level: {level}");
            }

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

4. Change appSettings.development.json to be:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "WebApplication2.Controllers.WeatherForecastController": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

5. Run the program, and from the swagger ui, expand "Get", click "Try it out", and click "Execute"

This output is CLOSER to what I'd expect:

```
Log level Trace is disabled.
Log level Debug is disabled.
Log level Information is disabled.
Log level Warning is enabled.
Log level Error is enabled.
Successfully logged to console at level: Error
Log level Critical is enabled.
Successfully logged to console at level: Critical
Log level None is disabled.
```

Oddly it says warning is enabled, but doesn't log anything at warning.

1. Modify program.cs to have the following lines before building.

```
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
var app = builder.Build();
```

Now the logging is what I'd expect.

```
  Log level Trace is disabled.
  Log level Debug is disabled.
  Log level Information is disabled.
  Log level Warning is disabled.
  Log level Error is enabled.
  Successfully logged to console at level: Error
  Log level Critical is enabled.
  Successfully logged to console at level: Critical
  Log level None is disabled.
```

From this I see a few questions:

1. In the minimal api scenario, calling LoggerFactory.Create doesn't seem to be using the appsetting.Development.json settings at all.  Is there a way to make it do that?
2. Using the logger created via dependency injection things seem to mostly work but the IsEnabled call doesn't match up with what it logs at.  When I was debugging I saw an eventlog logger that MinLevel = null and a Filter function.

[image]

This made me think to try clearing the collection of loggers, which seemed to get things exactly the way I wanted.

Comment: Can you please stop updating your question with new insights. You're invalidating previous answers. Stack overflow is not a forum, nor reddit, nor similar. Just one focusses stable question please.

Comment: My apologies.  Hopefully I'm done now.  I think I have two issues I'm struggling with, the difference between creating the logger with LoggerFactory.Create ( which doesn't seem to be using the setting from appSettings.Development.json at all ) and then a more obscure issue when using dependency injection where the IsEnabled doesn't seem to be in sync with what actually gets logged.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't set automatically, you have to set it while creating the logger:

```
var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(config =>
{
    config.AddConsole();
    var loglevel = (LogLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(LogLevel), builder.Configuration["Logging:LogLevel:MyCategoryName"]);
    config.SetMinimumLevel(loglevel);

}).CreateLogger("MyCategoryName");
```

Comment: I'm trying to get it so the log level is configured by appSettings.Development.json